# Understanding SwiftUI syntax: What is actually defined inside var body?

Tags: swiftui

Starting to learn `SwiftUI` I am a bit confused on how `Views`s are implemented. `View` is actually not a type but a protocol which requires a `var body` of type `View`.

**Problem 1:** So the protocol requires it self. Is this not an infinite, recursive loop? Implementation of `View` requires a var `body` that implements `View` which requires a var `body`... How does this work?

**Problem 2:** `var body` is usually implemented as computed property. This is nothing unusual. However, the implementation does not return anything but only "creates" subviews which are not explicitly added to their parent view. Initializing the sub views is enough.

This is not only the case with the `body` var but with all other views which include other views like `HStack`, `VStack`, etc.

```
struct SomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ViewA()
        OtherView()

        VStack {
           Sub1()
           Sub2() 
        }
    }
}
```

**How can this work? Is this valid Swift syntax?** I mean a "normal" computed property would look like this, wouldn't it?

```
var someValue: Int {
    let value1 = getValue()
    let value2 = SomeOtherValue()

    return value1 + value2
}
```

And not like this:

```
var someValue: Int {
    getValue()
    SomeOtherValue()
}
```

Comment: Of course it's valid Swift syntax, otherwise it would not compile. It uses the @ViewBuilder attribute, if you're wondering how it works under the hood. It's not infinite recursion because the basic building blocks, like `Text`, `Image`, etc. can act as the exit point.

Comment: Thanks @EmilioPelaez, the `@ViewBuilder` was the missing piece. This makes much clearer what is going on :-)